# Rails / CanCan: Authorization for multiple resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I'm building a rails app that has two distinct resources that represent types of users - tenants and landlords.

I have authentication for both set up via Devise, and authorization for one of the resources using CanCan.

I do not want to make them types of the same user resource, because they have different relationships with the other resources in the app (a property belongs_to a landlord, but has_many tenants, for example).

I have found lots of info about how to set up Cancan for a single resource with multiple roles (a user with an admin role, for instance), but am coming up empty about how to handle authorization for multiple resources at the same time.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok from the top of my head, you can do something like this:

--models>>ability.rb:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    if user.class.name=='Landlord' 
      can :manage, :all   
    elif user.class.name=='Tenant'
      can :read, :all
    else
     can :read, :all
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `role` column to the `users` table and populate this field with different roles.

```
$ rails generate migration AddRoleToUsers role:string
```

Update the `models/ability.rb` file to customize the authorization:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.nil?
      can :read, :all
    elsif user.role == "landlord"
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.role == "tenant"
      can :read, :all
      can :create, ToDoList
      can :update, ToDoList do |to_do_list|
        to_do_list.user == user
      end
      can :destroy, ToDoList do |to_do_list|
        to_do_list.user == user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If you do it this way, I would recommend the easy_roles gem. It is available on github and it is very convenient.